# Is it possible to heat water beyond the boiling point using a microwave?

Tags: physics, microwaves

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can microwaved water explode?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/303/can-microwaved-water-explode)

Is it possible to heat water beyond its boiling point using a microwave? Furthermore, is there  any truth to stories that such overheated water could explode?. Have any people been burnt while trying to heat up water in a microwave?

Comment: I'd say migrate to physics.se :)

Comment: off topic, where is skeptism here.

Comment: The word you want to google is "superheated".